# Sending second http request before the first http request enters success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a diagram where I drag and drop some elements onto it.

For a newly dropped element, I attach a property to this element with "new" as its value.

If I click on save button, a POST request will be made for this element. Inside the success callback, I change the above property's value from "new" to "old".

We also have auto save loop enabled in our application. So, an element can be saved either in auto save loop or by clicking on the save button.

Now, when auto save loop and clicking on save button happen almost simultaneously i.e,

one request is sent. Before it enters success callback, another request is sent. As a result, two POST requests are made for a single "new" element. How to avoid this?

We are using JavaScript and angularJS in our app.

Comment: do u have ajax loader image presented when doing POST ? You can detect the presence of such an image and prevent further POST

Comment: In angular there is a way to do this. When you launch the 2nd call your can defer the other promise (the first call). The tricky part is that each one should know the other one. I cannot help further without going into the code (with a plunker or a jsfiddle) but you can search this way. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q (function .defer())

Comment: Does the new element has any kind of id that could be used by the save method to keep track of requests being executed?